# Multiple list items based on value using python

Tags: python, list

I have a path: `orders/line/2/codes/code/4/value` and I need to create a list where I need to multiply the path based on number values within the path:

from this: `orders/line/2/codes/code/4/value`

to this:

```
[orders/line/1/codes/code/1/value,
orders/line/1/codes/code/2/value,
orders/line/1/codes/code/3/value,
orders/line/1/codes/code/4/value,
orders/line/2/codes/code/1/value,
orders/line/2/codes/code/2/value,
orders/line/2/codes/code/3/value,
orders/line/2/codes/code/4/value]
```

how could I achieve this the most efficient way?

The number of number values are changing each time, like: `orders/line/2/codes/code/4/values/value/5/kg` or even more tag.

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what your input looks like and and what you'd like your output to be, along with what you've tried already?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The number of number values are changing each time, like:  orders/line/2/codes/code/4/values/value/5/kg  or more, define the for loops should based on the count of number values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to generate the desired combinations of upperbounds for `range` objects:

```
from itertools import product

template = 'orders/line/{}/codes/code/{}/values/value/{}/kg'
numbers = [2, 4, 5]

print([template.format(*p) for p in product(*(range(1, i + 1) for i in numbers))])
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AuthenticSeashellGigahertz

Answer (score 1):

```
from pprint import pprint
result = []
for i in range(1,3):
    for j in range(1,5):
        result.append(f'orders/line/{i}/codes/code/{j}/value')
pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used f-string to modify the numbers

```
    final=[]
    for base in range(1,3):
        for inner in range(1,5):
        
            final.append(f"orders/line/{base}/codes/code/{inner}/value")
   for i in final:
    print(i)
```

**Outputs**

```
orders/line/1/codes/code/1/value
orders/line/1/codes/code/2/value
orders/line/1/codes/code/3/value
orders/line/1/codes/code/4/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/1/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/2/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/3/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/4/value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path = 'orders/line/2/codes/code/4/value'
vals = path.split('/')
for i in range(int(vals[2])):
    for j in range(int(vals[5])):
        print( os.path.join(vals[0],vals[1],str(i+1),vals[3],vals[4],str(j+1),vals[6]) )
```

**Output:**

```
orders/line/1/codes/code/1/value
orders/line/1/codes/code/2/value
orders/line/1/codes/code/3/value
orders/line/1/codes/code/4/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/1/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/2/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/3/value
orders/line/2/codes/code/4/value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a f-string and a list comprehension is pretty efficient;

```
paths = [f'orders/line/{i}/codes/code/{j}/value' for i in range(1,3) for j in range(1,5)]
```